# pytest: How to use temporary folders in a class-scoped fixture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Is there a way to share a temporary folder just across the tests in class?

This [pytest doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html) mentions the function-scoped tmp_path and session-scoped tmp_path_factory fixtures.  Didn't say anything about class scope.
The code below, as expected, does not work because it attempts to scope tmp_path fixture at the class level.  Is there a way to make it work?

```
import pytest

class TestMyClass:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def new_path(self, tmp_path):
        return tmp_path / 'subdir'

    def test_this(self, new_path):
       assert True

    def test_that(self, new_path):
       assert True
```

The error message is:

> test setup failed
> ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the function scoped fixture tmp_path with a class scoped request object, involved factories:

Comment: Using `@pytest.fixture` results in function scope.  A temporary directory is created for each test.  I'd like all test in the class to share one directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the path as a class attribute

```
class TestMyClass:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def new_path(self, tmp_path_factory):
        TestMyClass.__new_path = tmp_path_factory.mktemp('subdir') / 'dir'

    def test_this(self):
        print(self.__new_path)

    def test_that(self):
        print(self.__new_path)
```

Output:

```
TestMyClass::test_this PASSED                                [ 50%]
C:\Users\...\pytest-42\subdir0\dir

TestMyClass::test_that PASSED                                [100%]
C:\Users\...\pytest-42\subdir0\dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this as it's sort of counter intuitive to testing and there's likely a better alternative.

However, if you're adamant about taking this path, you can achieve it with the help of `tmp_path_factory`

```
import pytest

class TestMyClass:

    @pytest.fixture
    def new_path(self, tmp_path_factory):
        return tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp() / "subdir"

    def test_this(self, new_path):
        assert True

    def test_that(self, new_path):
        assert True
```

Comment: This creates a subdirectory for each test (i.e. "subdir0" and "subdir1").  Was looking for a directory that could be shared across the class.